# Why am I getting non-current information from my database under certain scenarios? MySQL/ Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I'm doing edge case testing, so it's involving me resetting a bunch of db rows to a previous state in Workbench and then repeating operations from my front-end/api.

I am having strange results. If I reset the data from Workbench, and then query the data from my api, I am getting the old data, not the updated data i just reset from Workbench. At  first i thought it was a front-end caching issue, but I turned caching off and stepped through my backend code and I am somehow getting outdated data. For example, this query

```
SELECT * FROM tournaments WHERE is_final = FALSE ORDER BY created ASC LIMIT 10
```

is returning different data to my backend when called from my spring boot jdbc connection, vs when called from MySQL Workbench.

When I rerun the spring boot app, and query the database, I get the correct updated data to my backend from the db. Which makes me wonder if there is some sort of jdbc caching functionality I don't know about? I thought this was only happening when I made Workbench changes to the database, but I ran into a scenario where i got only parts of the updated data when querying from my api.

What I mean is, I have a check

```
if((entryFromDatabase.getManagerId()!=null) || (entryFromDatabase.getManagerReportedResult()!=null))
            throw new ApiException("Tournament already completed and finalized");
```

This check is to verify that an action wasn't already performed. In db both of these are either always null, or always containing a value.

I performed the tournament finalization, twice in a row, I managed to return one of the values as null, and the other as not null. Its not an issue with the queries, or my row mappers. The data is not current when queryied from backend.

I have no idea what could be causing this. I'm not even sure if it seems like a Spring problem or a MySQL problem.

Do you have any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Are any "caches" involved?

Comment: No, no caches .

Comment: What transaction isolation level is the application using? Are you commiting the change?

Comment: Repeatable Read. I am committing at the end of every stored procedure. I think commit is implied in a normal update statement.